how to project caustics on non glass surfaces
https://www.artstation.com/artwork/zPnQBD
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/images/228291
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/images/228292
hello how to project caustics on non-glass surfaces like rocks, when you are in a cave and there are water caustics, these get projected onto the rock, especially visible in caves, any ideas? So far I had to paint caustics by hand, it is tedious

Rendering real caustics can be done with addons such as LuxCore, but its incredibly costly. I would recommend finding a way to project the effect of the caustics on to your surfaces using lights with image sequences or textures in them.

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

There is a solution based on putting a voronoi mask on a light, drawn from Polyfjord, a nice youtuber :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9YmJ0zGWHw
Here is the node setting on the light to achieve the effect:

